# Move a Content Builder Email from one Business Unit to another

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

Is there a way to move a Content Builder Email from one Business Unit to another. In Classic Email you could move it from BU to Shared then from the target BU you move it from Shared to BU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current CB system, you can **share** from BU1 to BU2, then from BU2 **copy** that email, and from BU1, **delete** it. Doesn't work if you want to keep the exact same email (new jobs won't know it's the same email etc.) but if you just want to build an email in one BU and then let another BU own, manage, and send it then this workaround might do.

Comment: This works perfectly. We are building in one BU for Testing then need to have a production version in another BU. Actually need to modify some of the Ampscript anyway for Production lookups, so this is just what I needed. A little cumbersome, but easy enough.